# box-shadow and its order of attributes

Tags: html, css

Looking at shadows (`box-shadow`) in CSS.
I have understood the basic values and its orders such as X and Y offsets relative to the element, blur and spread radius, and color(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) and I was fine.
Then I bumped into this interesting collection of shadow templates where you can copy their coding (https://getcssscan.com/css-box-shadow-examples) and I have got confused.
Fot example in one of the shadows it uses:

```
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px
-12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
```

It seems that 4 layers of shadows are overlapped, but why color is the first attribute? I would appreciate any thoughts about it.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [formal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow#formal_syntax) You can read:

> `<shadow> = inset? && <length>{2,4} && <color>?`

And for the `&&`:

> Separating two or more components, by a double ampersand, &&, means that all these entities are mandatory but may appear **in any order**. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Value_definition_syntax#double_ampersand)</sup>

Comment: I did not understand between the code 'box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;' and the a double ampersand, && which are not present. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: @Matteo the `&&` is not present, it's a part of the *formal syntax* to describe the rule the syntax should follow. did you follow the link I shared?